# How to let Okta users change their own profile settings from my app

Tags: okta

I am implementing react based app and need to implement a configuration setting, that users can change themselves (say, color theme).

I know how to add custom attribute to user profile and how to get user info through @okta/okta-react getUser method. But I could not find saveUser or similar.

From API docs I see /api/v1/users/me endpoint but it does not accept neither access token (says wrong token), nor id token (says invalid character in token).

So how do I let users who login into my application using Okta change their profile values for customization?

Is it possible at all or should I implement a table in my database to keep users' configuration? This would be the most unfortunate, for I chose Okta to minimize user maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm positive that this API call would require sending Okta session cookie, so make sure you include it in your request

Comment: It says that the following header should be sent "Authorization: SSWS ${api_token}". I tried to use both Access and ID tokens as api_token, but it didn't work. What is okta session cookie and where I get it from? I acquired both tokens using oktaAuth.getAccessToken() and oktaAuth.getIDToken() from library @okta/okta-react.

Comment: okta session cookie is the one which you obtain when logging into Okta, you can inspect it in your browser app/session storage. Tokens are useless, they are not a replacement for SSWS token.